# Replacing the list item fa fa icon class name with other class name

Tags: jquery, html, font-awesome

I have a code something like below

```
<ul> 
<li> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Name</li>  
<li> <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Email</li>
<li> <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> Mobile Number </li> 
</ul>
```

I tried to replace the class name **fa-map-marker** with **fa-user** by using jquery code as below

```
$('i').removeClass('fa-map-marker').addClass('fa-user');
```

but the class name getting applied for both name and email resulting same user icon for both name and email.

please help me how to sort this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simple as this: `$('i.fa-map-marker').removeClass('fa-map-marker').addClass('fa-user');`

`$('i.fa-map-marker')` will return all `<i>` that has the class `.fa-map-marker`

**Demo**

```js
$('i.fa-map-marker').removeClass('fa-map-marker').addClass('fa-user');
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul> 
<li> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Name</li>  
<li> <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Email</li>
<li> <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> Mobile Number </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution

```js
$('i.fa-map-marker').removeClass('fa-map-marker').addClass('fa-user');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul> 
<li> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Name</li>  
<li> <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Email</li>
<li> <i class="fa fa-mobile"></i> Mobile Number </li> 
</ul>
```

You can Edit or Preview Code [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/34g9fq2k/)